# Double loop over nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in Python like this:

```
funcs = {1:{-1:{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 0:{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 1:{'a': 5, 'b': 6}},
2:{-2:{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, -1:{'a': 9, 'b': 10}, 0:{'a': 11, 'b': 12}, 1:{'a': 13, 'b': 14}, 2:{'a': 15, 'b': 16}}}
```

It has three levels of nested dictionaries:

- the first level `m` keys run from `1` to some `N` (here `N = 2`)
- the second level `n` keys run from `-m` to `m`: for `m=1`, it is `-1, 0, 1`, for `m=2`, it is `-2,-1,0,1,2`
- the third level `p` keys run over `'a'` and `'b'`
- the values `1, 2, 3, ..., 16` are just sample values.

I need to run a function `g(x,y)` over each possible pair of values in the lowest level of the dictionary (so 16x16 operations). Obviously, I can do this by running over all keys in a 6-nested loop, but I was hoping for something more efficient and pythonic.

If the outermost level had only m=1, the resulting matrix would look like:

```
g(f[1][-1][a], f[1][-1][a]), g(f[1][-1][a], f[1][-1][b]), g(f[1][-1][a], f[1][0][a]), g(f[1][-1][a], f[1][0][b]), g(f[1][-1][a], f[1][1][a]), g(f[1][-1][a], f[1][1][b])
g(f[1][-1][b], f[1][-1][a]), g(f[1][-1][b], f[1][-1][b]), g(f[1][-1][b], f[1][0][a]), g(f[1][-1][b], f[1][0][b]), g(f[1][-1][b], f[1][1][a]), g(f[1][-1][b], f[1][1][b])
g(f[1][0][a], f[1][-1][a]), g(f[1][0][a], f[1][-1][b]), g(f[1][0][a], f[1][0][a]), g(f[1][0][a], f[1][0][b]), g(f[1][0][a], f[1][1][a]), g(f[1][0][a], f[1][1][b])
g(f[1][0][b], f[1][-1][a]), g(f[1][0][b], f[1][-1][b]), g(f[1][0][b], f[1][0][a]), g(f[1][0][b], f[1][0][b]), g(f[1][0][b], f[1][1][a]), g(f[1][0][b], f[1][1][b])
g(f[1][1][a], f[1][-1][a]), g(f[1][1][a], f[1][-1][b]), g(f[1][1][a], f[1][0][a]), g(f[1][1][a], f[1][0][b]), g(f[1][1][a], f[1][1][a]), g(f[1][1][a], f[1][1][b])
g(f[1][1][b], f[1][-1][a]), g(f[1][1][b], f[1][-1][b]), g(f[1][1][b], f[1][0][a]), g(f[1][1][b], f[1][0][b]), g(f[1][1][b], f[1][1][a]), g(f[1][1][b], f[1][1][b])
```

Comment: for you example you want to iterate over pair like : `(1,2), (3,4),(5,6)` and so on right?

Comment: No, over each possible pair at the lowest level, so `(1,1),(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), ..., (1,16), (2,1), (2,2), ..., (16, 16)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think what you need to use is `itertools.product`.
- First get list of all numbers you want to create combinations for. Then using `itertools.product` generate permutation of numbers.

```
import itertools
funcs = {1:{-1:{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 0:{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 1:{'a': 5, 'b': 6}},
2:{-2:{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, -1:{'a': 9, 'b': 10}, 0:{'a': 11, 'b': 12}, 1:{'a': 13, 'b': 14}, 2:{'a': 15, 'b': 16}}}

l = []
for k,v in funcs.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        l.extend(v1.values())

print(l)

combi = list(itertools.product(l, repeat=2))

# call fucn of each of combi
for val in combi:
    # print(foo(combi))
    pass
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, for example if you want to sum the `a,b` pairs of values and put them on a list:

```
funcs = {1:{-1:{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 0:{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 1:{'a': 5, 'b': 6}},
2:{-2:{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, -1:{'a': 9, 'b': 10}, 0:{'a': 11, 'b': 12},
1:{'a': 13, 'b': 14}, 2:{'a': 15, 'b': 16}}}

def g(funcs):

    return [sum(v2.values()) for v in funcs.values() for v2 in v.values()]
```

### Output:

```
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31]
```

Please tell me if you need a more specific application that's not easily generalizable from this.

Comment: Thanks, in practice I need to make a matrix `g[i,j]` from all possible pairs of values, not just from the ones belonging to the same branch. So `g` would be a a 16x16 matrix.

Comment: Could you post how a 3x3 matrix would look like if you managed to do what you're looking to do?